# Выровнять таблицу по центру

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5 imgsl_wrap">
  <img class="auto__img" src="img/auto1.jpg" alt="">
  <a href="#calculator" class="auto__btn">Оформить заказ</a>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-7">
  <table class="table table-striped auto__table text-left">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Грузоподъемность</td>
        <td colspan="2">0,5т. 1 место</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Тип борта</td>
        <td colspan="2">цельнометаллический</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Объем кузова</td>
        <td colspan="2">2 м.куб</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Размер кузова</td>
        <td colspan="2">194х95х98см</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Мин. заказ</td>
        <td colspan="2">1400руб на 2ч.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Цена за 1ч/1км</td>
        <td colspan="2">400руб/ч 10р/км</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда код]

на мобильных отображается слева

Answer (score 1):

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5 imgsl_wrap">
  <img class="auto__img" src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff" alt="">
  <a href="#calculator" class="auto__btn">Оформить заказ</a>
</div>
  
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-7">
  <table class="table table-striped auto__table text-left">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Грузоподъемность</td>
        <td colspan="2">0,5т. 1 место</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Тип борта</td>
        <td colspan="2">цельнометаллический</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Объем кузова</td>
        <td colspan="2">2 м.куб</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Размер кузова</td>
        <td colspan="2">194х95х98см</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Мин. заказ</td>
        <td colspan="2">1400руб на 2ч.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Цена за 1ч/1км</td>
        <td colspan="2">400руб/ч 10р/км</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Возможно какие-то ваши стили задают дополнительное выравнивание, но вот в примере именно таблица на всю ширину экрана для мобильных устройств (`xs-12`).